# attr(*, "internal.selfref")=<externalptr> appearing in data.table Rstudio

Tags: r, data.table

I am a new user of the R `data.table` package, and I have noticed something unusual in my data.tables that I have not found explained in the documentation or elsewhere on this site.

When using data.table `package` within Rstudio, and viewing a specific data.table within the 'Environment' panel, I see the following string appearing at the end of the data.table

> attr(*,"internal.selref")=<externalptr>

If I print the same data.table within the Console, this string does not appear.

Is this a bug, or just an inherent feature of data.table (or Rstudio)? Should I be concerned about whether this is affecting how these data are handled by downstream processes?

The versions I am running are as follows:
data.table Version 1.9.6
Rstudio Version 0.99.447
OSX 10.10.5

Apologies in advance if this is just me being an ignorant newbie.

Comment: Don't worry about it. However, data.table is meant for huge datasets where it doesn't make sense to `View` them, so you should break out of the habit.

Comment: @Roland one can't work with a data set without knowing what's going on it. I usually use something like `View(DT[sample(.N, 1000)])` and it works very fast for any data size.

Comment: Yeah, I use `View` routinely (in vanilla R, of course). Beyond dealing with biggish data, data.table is nice also for fast grouped operations and clear syntax.

Comment: @DavidArenburg That's clearly more sensible than clicking on the data.table in RStudio's environment pane. I've seen people do that and have their R instance hang and crash as a result.

Comment: RStudio shows the attributes of objects in that pane.  Try `attr(dt, "hello") <- 1` and look again.  You'll have two attributes showing. As Roland says, no big deal.

Comment: why use `view` over `print` accompanied by `str`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I actually asked Matt Dowle, the primary author of the data.table package, this very question a little while ago.

> Is this a bug, or just an inherent feature of data.table (or Rstudio)?

Apparently this attribute is used internally by data.table, it isn't a bug in RStudio, in fact RStudio is doing its job of showing the attributes of the object.

> Should I be concerned about whether this is affecting how these data are handled by downstream processes?

No, this isn't going to affect anything.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are curious about why this attribute is created, I believe it's explained in the [data.table manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf) under the section for setkey():

> In v1.7.8, the key<- syntax was deprecated. The <- method copies the whole table and we know of
>   no way to avoid that copy without a change in R itself. Please use the set* functions instead, which
>   make no copy at all. setkey accepts unquoted column names for convenience, whilst setkeyv
>   accepts one vector of column names.
>   The problem (for data.table) with the copy by key<- (other than being slower) is that R doesn’t
>   maintain the over allocated truelength, but it looks as though it has. Adding a column by reference
>   using := after a key<- was therefore a memory overwrite and eventually a segfault; the
>   over allocated memory wasn’t really there after key<-’s copy. data.tables now have an attribute
>   .internal.selfref to catch and warn about such copies. This attribute has been implemented in
>   a way that is friendly with identical() and object.size().
>   For the same reason, please use the other set* functions which modify objects by reference, rather
>   than using the <- operator which results in copying the entire object.